# php mail() not sending after upload to my host

Tags: php, email

I have just finished developing a website on my localhost where I tested the `mail()` function and it worked perfectly.

But when I went ahead and uploaded to my hosting, no email is coming trough. It looks as if everything is working, the validation is working and everything but no email is coming trough?

Comment: you should go to [ask]

Comment: provide relevant code for us

Comment: The code is a bit too big to post. And the syntax works just fine, it has to be an issue in my hosting. Thats why i didnt post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your host is blocking outgoing mail? It is quite common for hosts to limit mail functionality in the war against spam.

I would suggest to check with your hosting provider whether you have mail privileges.